# Struggling with python assignment

Tags: python

Hi I'm really new to python and I don't understand what's wrong with my function, here is my code:

```
def myfunc_1():
    my_file = open("ex1_sample_data.txt", "r")
    my_list = []
    for i in my_file:
        my_list.append(i)
    return my_list

print(myfunc_1())

def myfunc_2():
    file = open("ex1_sample_data.txt", "r")
    for string_line in file:
        string_line = string_line.strip()
        my_tuple = myfunc_1(string_line)
        my_list.append(my_tuple)
    return my_list

print(myfunc_2())
```

And every time I run it I keep getting this message:

```
TypeError: myfunc_1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: You did not report the definition of `myfunc_1()`.

Comment: Can you share whole code with us ? It will be easy to call this function.

Comment: I'm not sure if formatting issues occurred when you pasted your code into StackOverflow, but it would be very good practice to make sure you consistently indent your code in multiples of 4 spaces.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. If I create `ex1_sample_data.txt` as an empty file, I get a different error, `NameError: name 'my_list' is not defined` in `myfunc_2()`. You need to make a [mre]. You can [edit] the question. See [ask] for other advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line  in myfunc_2 is wrong:

`my_tuple = myfunc_1(string_line)`

That is because by your definition of `myfunc_1`, the function does not get any parameter as the input.

You can change it to

```
my_tuple = myfunc_1()
```

And you will see it works.

Comment: now its saying my_list is not defined

Comment: Well, that is basically because my_list is not defined in the myfunc_2. Is it clear for you what exactly you expect to have using those two functions? If you explain, I might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

The positional argument error you received means that you are giving data to 'my_func1()' but did not say in the function definition that 'my_func1()' takes anything.

Basically you need to make sure that my_func1 looks like:

```
def my_func1(some_var):
```

Instead of:

```
def my_func1():
```

Comment: Does it have to be a specific variable or any random one?

Comment: It depends on how you wrote my_func1. Name it whatever makes sense for your function as an input, then you can use that variable inside the function.

Comment: So if you had a function that made brownies, it might look like: def brownies(chocolate, flour, eggs, sugar):